# failed to move contents with std::move

Tags: c++, std, move, move-semantics

I'm trying to understand how std::move with a simple example (below).
Basically I'm trying to move to contents of p1 to p2, so p1 is empty after that, which doesn't happen though.

I guess I'm not using std::move properly. I would appreciate a lot if anybody could explain that to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    int * p1 = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        p1[i]=i;
    // moving contents of p1 to p2  
    int * p2 = std::move(p1);   
    // I was expeting p1 now to be empty but it's not...
    if(p1 != NULL)
        std::cout << "I'M NOT EMPTY\n";
    // prints I'M NOT EMPTY     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The move function is not guaranteed to clear the contents of the source object. It is, however, guaranteed to be left in such a state that you can safely destroy it or assign a new value to it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this
[Why does moving a pointer variable not set it to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452503/why-does-moving-a-pointer-variable-not-set-it-to-null) can clarify what´s going on in your code. As riv pointed out, there is no reason to std::move assign NULL to your pointer.

This reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move has good examples of undefined behaviors when using std::move.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `std::move` doesn't do what people new to C++11 often expect. It is defined by the C++ standard simply as a `static_cast`, so on its own it doesn't actually modify the object it is given. There is often an expectation that `std::move` will somehow clear or zero out the object being moved from, but as [explained here](http://crascit.com/2015/09/21/when-moving-doesnt-move/), that's not at all what the C++ standard requires.

Also, riv's answer is only partially correct. The guarantee he talks about is not really to do with `std::move`, it is more related to rvalue references and the guarantee is typically discussed in conjunction with move constructors and move assignment. If you want more background on `std::move`, rvalues, etc., I highly recommend [Thomas Becker's discussion](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) which is one of the internet's most referenced sites on the subject.